# Transpose a matrix then flip it over the anti-diagonal. What is the name of this operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What do you call a matrix operation where you transpose it and then flip it over its anti-diagonal? I find it very useful in electrical network analysis to flip the input and output of a two-port network.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_{11} & Y_{12} \\
Y_{21} & Y_{22}
\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_{22} & Y_{21} \\
Y_{12} & Y_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Not sure if this has a name, but mathematically, you may view it as a reversal of the order of the basis, or a similarity transform via the reversal matrix (the permutation matrix/antidiagonal matrix obtained by flipping the identity matrix from left to right).

Comment: Be careful that you are assuming each $Y_{i,j}$ is a scalar or has the required symmetries as matrices to make your example match the description.  Assuming scalars, note that this is a particular similarity transformation, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} A \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = B$.

Comment: @user1551 not widely known, this is called a Triple Axel, named after https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axel_Paulsen

Comment: @WillJagy Why triple but not double?

Comment: I doubt that this operation has a common name, although the permutation matrix I mentioned above in an $n\times n$ setting is often called the *exchange* matrix (sometimes denoted $J$).  A matrix which is left unchanged by this similarity transformation is called [centrosymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrosymmetric_matrix).

Comment: See this mathoverflow question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195031/is-there-a-standard-notation-for-off-diagonal-transpose